# Implementing Graphs using class function in python. (Assignment)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment about class functions so just point me to the right direction. I dont need the answer just a little help in visualizing the problem

According to our lesson, graphs are made out of sets of vertices and edges.
[image: Sample graph]

so `G = (V, E)`
When `V={v1, v2, v3, v4} and E = {(v1, v2), (v1, v3), (v2, v3), (v2, v4), (v4, v1), (v4, v3)}`

And I'm given a template code that looks like this:

```
class Vertex:
    def __init__(self, value=0):  # CAN ADD VAR
        self.key = None
        self.value = value

class Edge:
    def __init__(self, k1, k2, value=0):  # CAN ADD VAR
        self.key = (k1, k2)
        self.value = value

class Graph:
    def __init__(self):  # DO NOT MODIFY
        self._vertice = list()
        self._edges = list()
        self._vkeys = set()
        self._ekeys = set()

    def getV(self):
        return self._vertice[:]

    def getVkeys(self):
        return set(self._vkeys)

    def getE(self):
        return self._edges[:]

    def getEkeys(self):
        return set(self._ekeys)
```

I am supposed to use this class to implement a graph and make another class function that deals with directed and undirected graphs and tell whether they have an eulerian path or not

```
class DiGraph(Graph):
    def euler(self):
```

I just don't know how to think of the Graph class. Do I just think of it as a set of vertices and edges like the lesson described?

```
({Vertex},{Edge})
```

I hope someone can give me a hint

Comment: this may help [python graph](https://www.python-course.eu/graphs_python.php) or any data structure book in python

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case, you have a base class `Graph`. It contains all the parameters for the graph. Things like `edges`, `vertices`, etc. Then you have `DiGraph` which inherits from `Graph`. All the stuff from the base `Graph` class is accessible in the `DiGraph`. `DiGraph` has an additional function `euler`. From this `euler` implementation you should access variables from `Graph` and solve the problem.

**UPDATE**

To add vertices or edges to this class you have to access it from the outside:

```
graph = Graph()
graph._vertice.append(Vertex())
```

You can create some helper functions inside the `Graph` to add or manipulate it.

Here is a tutorial about inheritance int python:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

[https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: It is better to reference ***official*** documentations where possible. Many times I encounter such random resources with mistakes or unclear explanations that just confuse beginners even more. If you have any specific affiliation with this site you should clearly disclose it in your answer or else it might seem like spam

Comment: @Tomerikoo hmm, well it was the first thing that came when I did a quick google search.  I also thought that it would be easier to understand compared to the official documentation.

Comment: Easier doesn't always mean better. Would you prefer that I explain to you about your car's engine or a certified mechanic? I might explain good, but don't know nothing about engines... Just yesterday I encountered a question here by a beginner that quoted such site with completely misleading and false statements. If it's not official - there is no guarantee for what you're reading is true...

Comment: @Tomerikoo it totally depends on the context of the question. If I will ask you how to read some data from the database and you explain the whole database architecture and how it was implemented and its whole history from early 1970 it won't be useful to me. BTW I added the link to official documentation so chill.

Comment: I understand the inherited part but I don't understand how the Graph class takes in 1 argument. How do I fit in the Vertex and Edge to form the "Graph"?

Comment: @Raguel I'm not attacking you. I'm totally chill... I am just sharing what I recently encountered. It is not context-specific. I am just saying that those sites are not to be blindly trusted that's all. Where possible, it's always better to rely on official sources, unless you have an affiliation with this site in which case it should be disclosed

Comment: @Tomerikoo understandable, have a nice day. :D

Comment: @WinnyDaPoo it's better if you go by some data structure book  (in python with example )or video tutorial

Comment: @sahasrara62 Thank you hehhe. I think I'm starting to get it. The Graph class is sort of like a storage system where you store the vertex value and keys as well as edge value and keys? And the other helper functions are there to help you access it. I just have to find a way to store the Vertex and Edge right?

Comment: @WinnyDaPoo indeed it is. Check my updated answer and if it answers your question then please mark it as resolved.

Comment: @WinnyDaPoo kinda,  it stores all the vertices and edge objects and their property. still, I suggest you go to a proper tutorial, added an example above in the comment section, that might help